# Get Storage not installing on flutter

Tags: flutter, get, flutter-dependencies, flutter-getx

When I try to install get storage on flutter its not installing. here shows an error. here is the error image -
[image: Error hints]

Comment: What's your project's name? Is it perhaps also get_storage?

Comment: yes... project name was get_storage

Comment: Change the name of your project to something unique - it cannot have the same name as one of its dependencies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from the top of the screenshot, I can see that you named your project the same as the `get_storage` package's name.

and **you can't do it**, because it conflicts what flutter will consider packages in your project

so you can just change the project name and it will work fine